# Set attribute of a model to a certain value before saving

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ('number',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.initial.get('account', None):
            self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(account=self.initial.get('account'))



    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        m = super(OrderForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # my custom code was here

        if commit:
            m.save()
        return m
```

That works, except I need to set the "number" attribute of "Order" (which is required) to a certain number. I don't know how to do it. I tried adding:

```
self.fields['number'] = 50
```

inside the "save()" method, but I still get an IntegrityError when click save (obviously that's not the correct syntax but it hints at what I'm trying to do). Another problem I encountered to make matters worse is that I cannot even access the fields['number'] now because it's in the exclude Meta attribute (I don't want people to be able to edit it, or for it to be an ).

Should I be doing this in my model's "save()" method instead, or perhaps in the "**init**()"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it would be cleaner in the model. This would be the syntax in model's save method:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.number = 50
    super(Order, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

If you're really going to set it every time like that, then you can declare it right in the Order model as:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=50)
```

Comment: 50 is just an example. I'm going to generate it dynamically (pseudo incrementing). I also need to access the "initial.account" part of it. How would I do that in the model? Basically I want to read the number attributes of all the Orders that have account=SpamAccount.

Comment: You can run queries from your save() method, just like you can in a view.

Comment: i want to save it every time to 50, and do not want it to be sent from form. how should i do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that this is the sort of thing you should do in the "clean" method.  The django form-validation docs are [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).  Essentially it will give you a dictionary of cleaned fields and then allows you to do more complicated validation that requires the info from numerous fields.  The you can return the dictionary of the corrected data ... including anything that you need to add or override.

If you include the model's code then we could help a little more.

Answer (score 0):

you could have just put

```
m.number = 50
```

Where you have

```
# my custom code was here
```

`self.fields` is a list of fields, not their values. If you want to access the values, use `self.cleaned_data`. This doesn't help you in `self.save()` though, use `m.number` because `m` is the instance that was created.